# didEnterRegion - audio not playing - Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, avaudioplayer, cllocationmanager

I am updating an existing app to Swift.  The issue I am having is that the main purpose of the app is to play a sound file when the app gets to a specific location.  Everything works in the simulator, but it does not play the sound on the device.  If I add the background mode for audio and airplay, it works flawlessly.  Apple has rejected this as it doesn't use the audio all the time, just when it enters a region.  I did not have to have audio and airplay background mode enabled for iOS7.

I think it has something to do with the audioplayer being dealocated before it has a chance to be used.  I cannot figure out how to get it set properly.  There is this same question on StackOverflow for Objective C, but I cannot find anything similar for swift (and to me, this is what the answer to that question suggests and the way I had it set for iOS7).

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var myManager: CLLocationManager!
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var mySpeechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

func playSound()
{
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool)
{
    speak()
}

func speak()
{
    var myString = "This is the phrase I want to speak"
    var mySpeechUtterance:AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:myString)
    mySpeechUtterance.rate = 0.12
    mySpeechUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    mySpeechSynthesizer .speakUtterance(mySpeechUtterance)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!)
{
    playSound()
    scheduleAllLocations()
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myManager = CLLocationManager()
    myManager.delegate = self
    myManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    myManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SpeakMinder", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var error:NSError?

    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.delegate = self

    mySpeechSynthesizer.delegate = self
}
```

This is the complete code.  It works flawlessly if I have audio/airplay enabled in the background.  Doesn't play a sound or speak if I have the audio/airplay disabled in the background.  (Apple has rejected the app for having audio/airplay enabled)

Comment: What if you use a local notification instead?

Comment: The code that is listed is only half of what happens in the didEnterRegion.  The rest uses the SpeechSynthesizer to speak a phrase, after the sound is played.  That doesn't work either.  I took it out to try to make this an easier question.  If I can get the sound to work, I know the speech synthesis will work also.  I've spent an entire day just trying to get one sound file to play.  If background is enabled, no issues, if background is disabled, nothing.  And Apple rejects the app if the background is enabled.

Comment: I made a test app with the above code.  After MANY circles around the neighborhood, I have come to the same result.  If audio in background is enabled... works fine; if not, doesn't make a sound.  So any suggestions?

Comment: It seems you came to a dead end, as Apple's guidelines for background task forbid sounds played eventually without a notification use. But that's more of a guess, sorry I can't help any further.

Comment: I'm supposed to be getting a call from the review team to discuss the issue.  I'll post whatever update there is after that discussion.

Answer (score 0):

From the Technical Team

> If you are attempting to use AVSpeechSynthesizer from the background you should have the background audio key enabled. AVSpeech simply uses the same audio plumbing as playing any sound.

Regarding it working in iOS7 without having audio in the background enabled

> If this key was not required, you were most likely getting lucky due to a bug that we have since corrected.

And an app was approved today with the audio background enabled.

If you are rejected due to having audio enabled in the background for the Speech Synthesizer.

> Our own Location Based sample “Breadcrumbs" has the following enabled in the plist. You may point to this sample in your appeal.